# Conda Environment Exception

Tags: conda, snakemake, mamba

I am trying to use TOBIAS by using snakemake pipeline
https://github.molgen.mpg.de/loosolab/TOBIAS_snakemake

This is for Motif Analysis.
I do these steps:

```
git clone https://github.molgen.mpg.de/loosolab/TOBIAS_snakemake.git
cd TOBIAS_snakemake
conda activate tobias_snakemake_env
snakemake --configfile example_config.yaml --use-conda --cores 4


But every time I get 

CreateCondaEnvironmentException:
Could not create conda environment from /data/halimaakhter/opt/TOBIAS_snakemake/environments/tools.yaml:
Command:
mamba env create --quiet --file "/data/halimaakhter/opt/TOBIAS_snakemake/.snakemake/conda/12623a984fa886b9468f45a55cb21bd7_.yaml" --prefix "/data/halimaakhter/opt/TOBIAS_snakemake/.snakemake/conda/12623a984fa886b9468f45a55cb21bd7_"
Output:
```

every time I get exception for creating environment for wilson.yaml or, uropa.yaml or, tools.yaml or, tobias.yaml

I uninstalled anaconda and installed new anaconda and did these steps again but still getting the same error again and again.

Comment: Your question is tagged as both conda and mamba - which is installed on your system? And which version of Snakemake are you using?

Comment: what does `mamba env create --file "/data/halimaakhter/opt/TOBIAS_snakemake/.snakemake/conda/12623a984fa886b9468f45a55cb21bd7_.yaml" --prefix "/data/halimaakhter/opt/TOBIAS_snakemake/.snakemake/conda/12623a984fa886b9468f45a55cb21bd7_"` output?

Comment: Output:
Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides r 3.2.2* needed by r-ggplot2-2.0.0-r3.2.2_0
  - nothing provides r 3.2.2* needed by r-magrittr-1.5-r3.2.2_0
  - nothing provides libcurl 7.79.0 h2574ce0_0 needed by curl-7.79.0-hea6ffbf_0

Comment: @KeyboardCat, both of them are installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Snakemake and I found that the order of channels really matters to solve the conda env. Take this simple env:

```
channels:
  - bioconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python>=3.9
  - pandas
  - structlog
  - rich
  - pysam
```

It won't solve and gives an error about the package libcurl. However, just switching conda-forge to be listed first, the env is able to be solved:

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python>=3.9
  - pandas
  - structlog
  - rich
  - pysam
```

Try editing the yaml files for the environments to switch these two around if they don't work. I just ran into this error today and found this question before I realized what the problem was.